# Program outputs error thing '<function score at 0x036374F8>' and doesn't output correct info when calling function and printing it

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, error-handling

I'm trying to make my program print out the score('9') after being put through a pre-defined function but it's not printing out the correct thing.

```
x=8
  def score():
  globz=x
  print(globx)
  globx+=1
  return globx

x=(score)
print(x)
```

the shell displays:

> <'function score at 0x036374F8'>

Which is not what I wanted. Why am I seeing this instead of the output of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling your `score` function. The value you're seeing is a reference to the function itself.

Use `score()` to call it and capture its return value in your `x` variable:

```
x = score()
print(x)
```